# How to add conditional on Gutenberg's color theme-support?

Tags: theming, 9, wysiwyg

I've added the [Gutenberg](https://www.drupal.org/project/gutenberg) theme-support on my custom theme. I want to add conditional based on text color and background color. For example, selecting the black color background will reset the default text color to white and disable the black text option. Is there a solution or documentation about this?

Comment: If you are going to set background in the editor, you might as well use font color options as well.

Comment: @AyexeM I got both text and background color options. My goal is to give a good color contrast, such as the user can not pick blue text on blue background.

Comment: You cannot disable text colors based on bacground color. But you can override text color for elements with specific background colors via css :
.has-black-background { color: white; }

Comment: @AyexeM I've done that. I thought there is a way to add conditional.